# Naming methods that are registered to events

Tags: c#, .net, events, naming-conventions

Assume that I have a class that exposes the following event:

```
public event EventHandler Closing
```

How should methods that are registered to this event be named? Do you prefer to follow the convention that Visual Studio uses when it assigns names to the methods it generates (aka. +=, Tab, Tab)? For example:

```
private void TheClass_Closing( object sender, EventArgs e )
```

Or do you use your own style to name these methods?

I've tried different ways to name these methods (like `TheClassClosing`, `HandleClosing`, etc.). But I haven't found a good style to indicate that the intent of a method is to handle a registered event. I personally don't like the style (underscore) that Visual Studio uses to generate method names.

I know that registered event-handling methods are always private and that there is no naming convention like the one for methods that *raise* events (e.g., `OnClosing`).

Comment: While the verb "register" is used in this question, Microsoft frequently uses the verb ["subscribe."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two common options for naming is either after what the method does:

```
theObject.Closing += SaveResults;
```

Or alternatively after what the method handles:

```
theObject.Closing += ClosingHandler;
```

Which is preferable really depends a bit on context.

In the first case it is immediately clear what the handler is going to do, which makes the code registering the handler more readable... but looking at the handler `SaveResults` in isolation it is not going to be necessarily obvious when it is going to be called, unless the event arguments have an obvious name (`ClosingEventArgs` or some such).

In the second case, the registration is more opaque (okay, so what is going to happen when `Closing` happens?), but on the other hand, looking at the handler implementation it will be obvious what is going on.

I guess the one to choose depends on which of the two you want to be more obvious; the site of the registration, or the implementation of the handler.

Or alternatively, you can go for the unholy combination of both methods:

```
theObject.Closing += ClosingHandlerSaveResults;
```

Now both the registration site and the implementation are equally obvious, and neither looks particularly elegant (plus, it probably violates the DRY principle).

For the record I prefer the first naming scheme when `theObject` is contained in a different scope from the implementation of `SaveResults`, and the second scheme when I am wiring up handlers to events that are all contained within the same class.

Answer (score 5):

Name it after what the handler actually does.

```
// event += event handler
saveButton.Click += SaveData();
startButton.Click += StartTheTimer();
```

Comment: I'm glad to see I'm not the only one who does this. Methods should say what they do, not how they happen to be used. It's the job of the event wiring to make that clear :)

Comment: @DavidRR: Well that's guidance on naming the delegates themselves - which is rarely relevant these days with `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`. I certainly wouldn't want to have a separate delegate type for every event ever created. The OP's question doesn't ask about naming the delegate, as they're using `EventHandler`. Basically I think your answer isn't an answer to the question that's been asked...

Comment: To give context to Jon's comment which is in response to an answer of mine that I have deleted, Microsoft does provide guidance for [naming **event handlers** (delegates used as types of events)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But the term "event handler" used in this context is *not* the same as a method that is subscribed (registered) to an event.

Answer (score 0):

I name my event handlers similarly to those created by Visual Studio (the +,=,tab,tab you mention).  I try to keep my naming consistent in my code, and I know that I will be creating handlers with the VS auto-creator at least some of the time.

The underscores don't bother me.

Answer (score 0):

maybe: OnObjectNameEventName, such as

```
private void OnTheClassClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This matches the internal event methods, and with the addition of the object name, it should help differentiate, besides, the method to raise events are essentially internal event handlers

User clicks form, form calls OnClicked, does its thing, then raises the Clicked event, it would only be natural from my point of view.

Comment: Due to MFC, the "OnSomeEvent" style is ingrained in many programmers (myself included). Unfortunately Microsoft decided to change the meaning of this to "send an event" rather than "receive an event", which makes a lot of the .net code unnecessarily confused. I now use RaiseSomeEvent to send an event, and have adopted the nasty but clear Sender_EventName() convention. I use Many_EventName() in the case where one event handler is attached to more then one sender.

Comment: @Jason: So when you decide to attach to another sender, you have to rename your method? I like the RaiseSomeEvent name though... maybe I'll start to use that instead of OnSomeEvent... always found the latter a bit... wrong...