# Organizing Event Handlers Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, event-handling

I use asp.net and c# in web forms.

Using Visual Studio it creates automatically Event Handlers Methods for my controls.
VS generate the Method name in this way `idControl_event`. I know I can give any name to Event Handlers Methods.

- So I'm wondering what is your favorite approach at naming theme.
- I would like to know if using Web Forms is possible to write Event Handlers Method in a separate class (not in code behind for a specific web page) and how to call theme from the Control.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to separate the event handlers from the code-behind?

Comment: I read this architectural approach in a book "C# 2008 Objects" referring as a pattern that could be use in Windows Applications. The main ideas is to have common logic in a single place for many Controls... so I was interested in see if could apply even on Web Forms.

Comment: Hmm that gave me another idea about using a base class to encapsulate the common logic - I've updated my answer to include that option as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For event handler names, I generally use the format that Visual Studio generates by default: [idControl]_[eventName].  But that is very much a personal/team preference.  I've seen similar discussions about this such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317109/naming-c-events-and-handlers-properly) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963645/how-to-name-methods-that-are-registered-to-events).  Regardless of how you choose to name the event handlers, I think the most important thing is to remain consistent.

As for having the event handlers outside of your code behind, I haven't seen this done very often but it is possible.  The easiest way would be to have a static method in the separate class with the common event handling logic.  For example, here is how you could have standard logic for Page.Loaded in a separate class.  I believe you'll need to register the event handler via code - I don't think you can do it in markup (aspx).

```
public static class CommonEventHandlers
{
    public static void Page_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do any standard logic

        //If you need a reference to the page that raised the event, 
        //   you can get it from the 'sender' parameter.
        Page page = (Page)sender;

        //Do something with 'page'
    }
}
```

Then in the code-behind of the page that you want to use that common event handler:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public WebForm1()
    {
        //Register the handler via code in the constructor
        Load += CommonEventHandlers.Page_Loaded;
    }
}
```

As another option, you could use inheritance to help with code reuse.  For example, you could have a base class that your Pages inherit from that has standard handlers.  One benefit of this is that you can register event handlers in markup even if the method is declared in a base class so you don't need to do anything in the code-behind of the ancestor page.

Comment: would the OP also need to set AutoEventWireup to false to use this?

Comment: @Tim - `AutoEventWireup` won't affect this approach.  However, if you happened to have a method called `Page_Load` in the page and `AutoEventWireup` was `true`, that `Page_Load` method **and** the one in `CommonEventHandler` would both be called.  But I think that would be expected - and perhaps even desired in case you wanted some standard processing (in `CommonEventHandlers`) and custom processing (in `Page_Load`) to occur.

Comment: Interesting.  If the order the events were fired in was always known and guaranteed to be the same (i.e., code-behind then CommonEventHandlers) that could lead to some interesting design possibilities. Although I'm still not sure there wouldn't be better approaches out there.

Comment: some more explanation about AutoEventWireup can be found here http://forums.asp.net/p/932513/1096656.aspx

Comment: In theory, I don't believe the order is guaranteed.  But in practice, event handlers are called in the order they were registered (just don't quote me on that).  So in the case above, the 'CommonEventHandler' one would be called first (it gets registered in the constructor which is much earlier than when AutoEventWireup happens).  Either way, I agree that having multiple event handlers that depend on a certain order is a bad sign.

Comment: Thanks Stephen I understand you point about using a base class.. what would be pro and cons or both your approches?

Comment: The one drawback of using a base class is that C# doesn't have multiple inheritance (which is probably a good thing but that's another story).  So for example, if you had common code that you wanted to use and put it in a BasePage like my example, that's fine if you're just sharing the code in other pages.  But then if you wanted to make a control, you couldn't use BasePage as it's base class anymore.  But other than that limitation, I think it's cleaner to use base classes and it just 'feels' right :-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have the event handlers in another class, best you could get would probably be inside a separate partial class file

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Powell said, I'm pretty sure the best you can do with events is to have them in a different file as a partial class for your code-behind.

Regarding the naming convention, 95% of the time I see events named like you said - `idControl_event`. That's the way I name them, as it makes it easy to tie the code to the control when I'm looking at the source.